# How to arrange same Property names together and give border on end of each similar property using javascript

Tags: javascript, jspdf

i am using `jsPdf`. I need to convert the json data into pdf without using templates.
So, i have done to some extent, but now i need to bring similar names Actuals together and put border line after each property.
Can anyone help me to find solution to this?

DEMO: [DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jdzg6s?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

[image]
TS:

```
captureScreen() {
  this.displayTable = true;
  let grossItems = [];
  grossItems.push(this.grossItems);
  var doc = new jsPDF();

  for (let i = 0; i < this.actualTotal.length; i++) {
    var temp = [];
    temp.push(this.actualTotal[i].category); // ADDED
    console.log(temp, "category")
    for (let key in this.actualTotal[i]) {
      temp.push(this.actualTotal[i].baseAmount); // CHANGED HERE
    }
  }

  this.actual.push(temp)

  for (let i = 0; i < grossItems[0].actualExpenses.length; i++) {
    var temp = [];
    temp.push(grossItems[0].actualExpenses[i].category); // ADDED

    for (let key in grossItems[0].actualExpenses[i]) {
      temp.push(grossItems[0].actualExpenses[i].baseAmount); // CHANGED HERE
    }

    this.rowsParent.push(temp)

    for (let j = 0; j < grossItems[0].actualExpenses[i].expenses.length; j++) {
      var temp = [];
      temp.push(grossItems[0].actualExpenses[i].expenses[j].category); // ADDED
      for (let key in grossItems[0].actualExpenses[i].expenses[j]) {
        temp.push(grossItems[0].actualExpenses[i].expenses[j].baseAmount); // CHANGED HERE
      }

      this.rows.push(temp);
    }
  }

  const mergedArray = [...this.actual, ...this.rowsParent, ...this.rows]
  doc.autoTable(col, mergedArray, {
    theme: "plain",
    startY: 45,
    margin: {
      top: 45
    },
    drawHeaderRow: (head, data) => {
      data.doc.setLineWidth(0.7);
      data.doc.setDrawColor(0, 0, 0);
      data.doc.line(
        data.cursor.x,
        data.cursor.y,
        data.cursor.x + data.table.width,
        data.cursor.y
      );
      data.doc.line(
        data.cursor.x,
        data.cursor.y + head.height,
        data.cursor.x + data.table.width,
        data.cursor.y + head.height
      );
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: just a tip, you could use additional variables to short long property accessors.

Comment: @NinaScholz thanks for response, sorry i didnt get you

Comment: fo example for `grossItems[0]` take `grossItem = grossItems[0]` and for the next level take another variable, like `actualExpense = grossItem.actualExpenses[i]` and so on. but you could take a `for ...of` syntax and omit long accessors, because you take a variable for the actual item.

Comment: ya thanks for the suggestion, il update my code.Any idea to achieve the output?